# Eclipse (STS) Open Resource "Show In" menu

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

When using STS 3.7.1.RELEASE (on Windows, based on Eclipse Mars.1 4.5.1), I'd like to navigate to a file using "*Open Resource*" dialog and show the file in Package or Project Explorer using the "*Show In*" button.

But the *Show In* menu only shows "*Terminal*" and no "*Project Explorer*" option. Why is that and how can I fix it? Are there any options to be configured to get it working?

Comment: I think this is related to the type of the file. As a workaround, you can enable "link with editor" in the explorer to auto-select the file that is in the active editor. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Actually, I've found this working in original Eclipse. Not working in STS.

Comment: It may depend on perspective, context etc. Menus in eclipse are very context sensitive. So... more info is needed to make sense of this. Maybe a screenshot of the desktop when you click on the the context menu might provide the necessary info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 years later, that has been fixed with [Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#showin-action-project-explorer):

> The Show In context menu is now available for an element inside a resource project on the Project Explorer.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/showin_project_explorer.png]

Comment: I can't even remember what STS is anymore... But, nice, thank you :)

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik Eclipse STS: https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all: Spring Tools Suite. (https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-sts-spring)